# Why is Page load event not firing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pageload

My project name is sbmanager and in that project 
I have a page named  mgrGridHome.aspx
This page has the following reference:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="sbmanager.mgrGridHome" MasterPageFile="~/masterpages/global.master" %>
```

That has a label on it:

```
<asp:Label id="lblCurrentTime" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

In my mgrGridHome.aspx.cs file I have  the following:

```
protected void page_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            lblCurrentTime.Text = "See Me"; 
        }
```

But when I compile and run the page the label value is not set as if the page load has not fired.

But if I place the same code directly on the page like this:

```
<script language="C#" runat="server">
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        <asp:Label id="lblCurrentTime" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    }
</script>
```

The label value is set.

All I want to do is set the label value when the page loads. At the moment I don't care if it is a post-back or not. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Could you add `<%@ Page AutoEventWireup="true" ... %>`, and also make sure method name is `Page_Load`?

Comment: That worked. I did not know that the Case of Page_Load mattered.

Comment: Of course it matters! C# (and most programming languages) are case sensitive. You see in your question where you say "place some code"? You don't place "same code". It's different. Fixing programming problems often turns into a game of "find the difference".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Moved from Comment -

1. Add AutoEventWireup at Page - `<%@ Page AutoEventWireup="true" ... %>`
2. Also ensure event name is `Page_Load`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is solved by Win's answer. But for improving answer for other people with the same problem:
if you use `AutoEventWireup="false"` 
Make sure you have this lines in your code

```
 public yourclassname()
    {
        Load += Page_Load;
    }
```